# Equality operator for a structure in C++/CX`

Tags: visual-c++, struct

I have implemented a value structure in C++/CX. For initializing a vector of the structure I need to implement an Equality operator which is necessary in the IndexOf() operator of a vector as present in Collection.h.

But I am unable to create one.Can some one help me with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
struct typePerson {
  string firstName;
  string lastName;

  typePerson(string firstName,string lastName) : firstName(firstName), lastName(lastName) {}  

  bool operator==(const typePerson& p2) const {
    const typePerson& p1=(*this);
    return p1.firstName == p2.firstName && p1.lastName == p2.lastName;
  }
};
```

Sample Usage:

```
int main() {
  typePerson p1("John","Doe");
  typePerson p2("Jane","Doe");
  typePerson p3("John","Doe");

  if (p1 == p2)
    cout<<"p1 equals p2"<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"p1 does not equal p2"<<endl;

  if (p1 == p3)
    cout<<"p1 equals p3"<<endl;
  else
    cout<<"p1 does not equal p3"<<endl;


  return 0;
}

---------- Capture Output ----------
p1 does not equal p2
p1 equals p3

> Terminated with exit code 0.
```